# File saved in getFilesDir() is lost on app restart

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android programming, so the answer to my question is hopefully an easy one.

I have an app that can receive a file from a pc program that connects via the network. This file is then stored internally and used by the app. When the app starts, it reads the file (which is a serialized instance of the class 'WordList' which is basically a HashMap) and displays data from it to the user. At any time, the pc program can send a new file to the android device which receives the file and overwrites the old one in memory.

The file is received and stored like this:

```
try(ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port)){

    Socket pc = serverSocket.accept();
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(pc.getInputStream());
    list = (WordList)ois.readObject();
    ois.close();
    pc.close();

 }catch(IOException | ClassNotFoundException e){
     //Display error message and stuff
 }

 try {
     ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(
                               openFileOutput("save.dat", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
     oos.writeObject(list);
     oos.flush();
     oos.close();
 } catch (IOException e) {
     //Display error message and stuff
 }
```

When the app starts, it reads the file like this:

```
if (new File(getFilesDir() + "save.dat").exists()) {

     try {
         ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(
                                  new FileInputStream(getFilesDir() + "save.dat"));
         WordList list = (WordList)ois.readObject();

         /*Now set a reference to the list object so it can be used by the app, 
         then start displaying stuff to the user...*/
         ModelController.getInstance().setList(list);
         ModelController.getInstance().start(this);
     }catch(IOException | ClassNotFoundException e){
         //Display error message and stuff
     }
 }else{ 
     //Display error message and stuff
 }
```

The problem is that the app can't find the file when it starts. If I send a new file from the pc, it is received and used correctly, without error messages. But if I restart the app it is not found, I get the error message from the 'else' part of the last code block. What am I forgetting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
new File(getFilesDir() + "save.dat")
```

should be

```
new File(getFilesDir(), "save.dat")
```

the last one appends the file separator between the return value of `getFilesDir()` and `"save.dat"`

Instead of using

```
  new FileInputStream(getFilesDir() + "save.dat")
```

us

```
openFileInput("save.dat")
```

[here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileInput(java.lang.String)) you can find the documentation

Answer (score 0):

You can probably check where the save.dat is on the disk.

My hypothesis is to change the save to:

```
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(
                     openFileOutput(getFilesDir() + "save.dat", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
```